# Convertir fecha string en formato fecha

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy tomando los datos desde el back y la fecha me la trae en el siguiente formato

> 2022-10-11T01:32:25.948Z

Ya probe de usar las funciones de javascript para cambiar el formato y no me lo toma.
Necesito que el formato sea. dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Por lo que entiendo react me esta trayendo esto en string por eso no esta funcionando las funciones de javascript

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el string, puedes pasarlo al constructor de Date y  usar la función [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) para obtener un string con el formato local deseado. Por ejemplo, el de España "es-ES".

O [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) y [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) para obtener fecha y hora por separado en dicho formato.

```js
date = new Date("2022-10-11T01:32:25.948Z")
console.log(date.toLocaleString("es-ES"))
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("es-ES") + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString("es-ES"))
```

Si estas opciones no se ajustan a tus necesidades, usa una combinación de las otras [funciones disponibles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) o una librería como [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)